# Firebase Cloud Firestore retrieve data

Tags: php, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I have been reading the Firestore documentation for PHP on how to retrieve the data. I saw one from this link https://googlecloudplatform.github.io/google-cloud-php/#/docs/cloud-firestore/v0.3.2/firestore/query but I cannot retrieve the data. Anyone got solution/s?

```
 $collectionReference = $firestore->collection('notifications');
    $query = $collectionReference->where('so_id', '=', $so_id);
    $snapshot = $query->documents();
    foreach ($snapshot as $value) {
        echo $value['name'] . PHP_EOL;
    }
```

Comment: here should be double equal signs `where('so_id', '==', $so_id)`

Comment: An equality check is indeed indicated by `==`. See the docs here: https://googlecloudplatform.github.io/google-cloud-python/latest/firestore/query.html

Comment: Use $value->get('name')

Answer (score 0):

```
$collectionReference = $firestore->collection('notifications');
    $query = $collectionReference->where('so_id', '=', $so_id);
    $snapshot = $query->documents();
    foreach ($snapshot as $value) {
        echo $value->get('name');
    }
```

You must use `->get('fieldName')` for first values. If that values got nested values you need to do this. `->get('fieldName')->nestedFieldName()`